# Job Scheduler and Work manager conflict when Configuration.Builder() called in MyApplication() Android

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-workmanager, conflicting-libraries

So, I declared my Worker Class *NotifyWorker* and called it in the *MainActivity* with the below code :

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;

import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.JobManager;
import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.config.Configuration;
import com.birbit.android.jobqueue.log.CustomLogger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //some code
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(checkForUpdate(this)){
            return;
        }
         //some code

        final OneTimeWorkRequest notificationWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotifyWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag(workTag)
                .build();


        //WorkManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).beginUniqueWork(workTag, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, notificationWork);
        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplication()).enqueue(notificationWork);
        Log.v(TAG,"Worker executed");

        //Set content
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //some code
}
}
```

So, I got the following error on running the app:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

So, I followed [The developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#custom) , added the required code to my manifest, But i am unable to add the following method in *myApplication()* class :

```
class MyApplication extends Application implements Configuration.Provider {
    @Override
    public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
                .build();
    }
}
```

My application class looks like below :

```
public class xxxApplication extends Application implements androidx.work.Configuration.Provider {
    private static xxxApplication instance;
    private JobManager jobManager;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    public xxxApplication(){
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        //ensure jobmanager is configured
        getJobManager();
        broadcastReceiver=new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    private void configureJobManager(){
        Configuration.Builder builder = new Configuration.Builder(this)
                .customLogger(new CustomLogger() {
                    private static final String TAG = "JOBS";
                    @Override
                    public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void d(String text, Object... args) {
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format(text, args));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void e(Throwable t, String text, Object... args) {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format(text, args), t);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void e(String text, Object... args) {
                        Log.e(TAG, String.format(text, args));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void v(String text, Object... args) {

                    }
                })
                .minConsumerCount(1)
                .maxConsumerCount(3)
                .loadFactor(3)
                .consumerKeepAlive(120);
        //configure here if job scheduler involved
        jobManager = new JobManager(builder.build());

    }
    public synchronized JobManager getJobManager() {
        if (jobManager == null) {
            configureJobManager();
        }
        return jobManager;
    }

    public static xxxApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public **Configuration** getWorkManagerConfiguration() {   //I get some conflict here , resolved by using androidx.work.Configuration as a return type
        return  Configuration.Builder()    // Can't resolve the issue ?? what do i write here??
                    .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
                    .build();

    }

}
```

I have commented the part where i get an issue , syntax error says *"Method call expected"* . How do I resolve this issue?? Why is it not working as expected? Is there a conflict between JobManager and WorkManager configurations?

**UPDATE :** So,there was actually a conflict between the configuration files of *jobmanager* and *workmanager* .Had to call the later using full location definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this myself, in case it is useful for others who have used *Job-Schedulers* before, and are now adding background processes using *WorkManager* .
While adding the extension as specified in the [Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#custom)  for custom initialization , use the following code in case you have already used *JobScheduler* in your application class :

```
public class xxxApplication extends Application implements androidx.work.Configuration.Provider {
//OTHER CODE
@Override
    public androidx.work.Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new androidx.work.Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
                .build();
    }
}
```

However, it is recommended that you migrate all the processes to *WorkManager* to avoid further conflicts.